# setting initial viewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

im trying to set the initial view controller if a user has a token in his keychain.

when I try to set it in the appDelegate like this

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            let accessToken: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "accessToken")
    if accessToken != nil
    {
        // Take user to a home page
        let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! ViewLoader
        self.window.rootViewController = homePage
    }
    return true
}
```

but I get som errors saying "Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'window'"

it tried to clean the project but without luck

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your error is you do not declare a variable window.

Adding following code in your AppDelegate class is a solution for error:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home")
    self.window?.rootViewController = homePage
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
  }
  // ..... more code ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help but it makes no differnce

Comment: No problem. It should make a difference because window now belongs to AppDelegate. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Point is you shouldn't be getting the same error because we added a variable window to AppDelegate.

Comment: thanks just tried it out and now im not getting the error anymore but it still doesent change the initial view controller

Comment: You are missing     self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() . See my updated answer.

Comment: it dident workm it made no difference at all

Comment: Are you getting an error? Make sure your ViewController has the identifier "home" in your main.Storyboard.

Comment: it has the identifier home and no errors

Comment: No error, no warning? It's odd. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homePage = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home") as! ViewLoader
window?.rootViewController = homePage

window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Init window first and add the function `makeKeyAndVisible`.

Comment: @Sammy Yeah, we cann't use window if it doesn't exist.